# How do I set the word spacing when using a specific font with fontspec?

Tags: fonts, spacing, xetex, memoir

I have a custom font that I use, but the words are always too close together. Can I fix this so that whenever this font is used, the spacing is the same? Something in `em` or similar would be great. I'm currently inserting `~~` when needed ... hardly ideal!

Below is an MWE, with `MYFONT`instead of the font I use. I can't share it, sorry!

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\fontspec{MYFONT} kerning AV fi Ri fi fl fj

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\fontspec` should never be used directly in the document body; it's much better to define all fonts beforehand.

Not related, but `xunicode` should not be loaded along with `fontspec`;  `fontenc` is generally useless along with `fontspec`.

You can use the `WordSpace` feature. Experiment with the factor, in the example below the effect is exaggerated to show it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % just for testing
\newfontfamily{\myfont}{TeX Gyre Adventor}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  WordSpace={10},
]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmy}{\myfont}

\begin{document}

This is the standard font

\textmy{kerning AV fi Ri fi fl fj}

This is the standard font again

\end{document}
```

You can also use the switch `\myfont` (similarly to the relation between `\textsf` and `\sffamily`).

[image]