# fontdimen2 in Beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex

How can we make the effect of the command `fontdimen2\font=[size]` globally available in Beamer? The effect of this command seems to only affect the main text but not any other elements.

Here is my MWE with XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fontspec}

\title{Beamer-Test}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setmainfont{AlegreyaSans}[  
  Extension = .otf,  
  UprightFont = *-Regular,  
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,  
  BoldFont = *-Bold,  
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,  
  Ligatures = TeX
  ]

\fontdimen2\font=10pt  

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{A test frame}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can see in the picture, the main text and the first level bullet list text are correctly displayed, but the words spacing in the title of the frame, and the second level bullet list do not change the spacing.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Beamer already loads this for you.

Comment: Also unrelated: If possible, I would suggest to use lualatex instead of xelatex. xelatex causes several problems in beamer

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300836/36296 how to change the word space with fontspec. For your example this gives https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Awp.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you for your suggestion and the answer. It works perfectly. I now just wonder why the `\fontdimen2` not work globally in beamer.

Comment: Elements like subitem and frametitle use a different font size. You would see the same in `\documentclass{article}

\fontdimen2\font=10pt  

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum

\small

Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
`

Comment: the primitive `\fontdimen` changes exactly one font.